# how to identify the code which is receiving by my website

Tags: php

i make one php script who send the data one api after successful submission it will reply with all codes which i dont know how to read it. i make one php script who send the data one api after successful submission it will reply with all codes which i dont know how to read it.

```
{
  "ErrorCode": "000",
  "ErrorMessage": "Success",
  "JobId": "b770e8c9-118b-4347-9708-fcd1176c51d7",
  "MessageData": [
    {
      "Number": "918237020012",
      "MessageParts": [
        {
          "MsgId": "918237020012-9be10ca3793b4e7c83c74d3dfbbfd60d",
          "PartId": 1,
          "Text": "testing completed"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Read [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

This "codes" is called Json Object and in your case it's string encoded so you can decode it into a PHP object something like:

```
$obj = json_decode($response);
```

and you can access it's attributes like this:

```
echo $obj->JobId;
```

furthermore you can refer to the PHP documentation [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

They are called [JSON Strings](http://www.json.org/). It's a lightweight data-interchange format.

To decode the JSON string in PHP use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Like this,

```
$json_object=json_decode($jsonString);
```

It will return you PHP **Object** by default and you just need to read the Object properties. Like this,

```
echo $json_object->json_key;
```